# Pandas: efficiently search one dataframe using data from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

I have two pandas dataframes: one containing some 35'000 locations and another containing some 550'000 (Latin) inscriptions. They look roughly like this (abridged):

```
locations
     period               name  long    lat     latlong  [...]                     stem
0        R                Roma  50.4   1.23   50.4,1.23  [...]                      Rom
1       GR           Londinium  52.2   3.45   52.2,3.45  [...]          Londini, Londin
2       RL   Colonia Agrippina  54.0   6.78   54.0,6.78  [...]  Coloni, Colon, Agrippin
3        G           Vindobona  55.8   9.01   55.8,9.01  [...]                 Vindobon
4        R  Lutetia Parisiorum  57.6  -3.21  57.6,-3.21  [...]  Luteti, Lutet, Parisior
[...]
```

```
inscriptions
     id                 text  findspot  [...]      comment
0    a0            some text  Brindisi  [...]          n/a
1    a1  some different text  Bath      [...]         viri
2    a2       text with name  Bern      [...]  tria nomina
3    a3   text with Romensis  Berkeley  [...]     mulieris
4    a4            long text  Bonn      [...]          n/a
[...]
```

I'm trying to find all inscriptions which contain a location in adjective form. For that, I currently iterate over all 35'000 rows of the location dataframe using `df.iterrows()`, extract the stem of each location name, and use a regex to find the different possible forms in each inscription text (so that here 'Rom' would find 'Romensis' in inscriptions[3][text]; an English comparison would be that I use 'Boston' to find 'Bostonian', 'Bostonians', 'Bostonite', 'Bostonitesse', etc.). If a match is found, I copy the inscripton row to a new dataframe and add the details from the location dataframe (such as longitude and latitude) as new columns:

```
matches
     id                 text  findspot  [...]      comment  name  long    lat     latlong  [...]
0    a3   text with Romensis  Berkeley  [...]     mulieris  Rome  50.4   1.23   52.2,3.45  [...]
[...]
```

This means that I iterate some 35'000 times over a 550'000 rows long dataframe, which unsurprisingly takes forever (after some 12 hours, the code made it through 4% of the first dataframe, meaning the whole thing would take weeks).

I thought about using `np.where()`, but in this way I could only add, say, the GPS coordinates to the inscription dataframe, but not also the name of the place, and there are several different places which have the same or a very similar name, and I don't see how using `np.where()` would allow me to collect them all (i.e. have a new row containing all the relevant information for each matching pair).

Similarly, `df.apply()` using a lambda would have similar restrictions as far as I undertand it.

Is there a way to achieve the functionarlity what is essentially two nested for-loops without its performance drawbacks? Thank you very much for some ideas, and I'd be happy to expand on the problem if there are questions.

Comment: My idea (which I have never tested) would be to create a monstrous regular expression with all stems connected with `|`. As I said I don't know if this is even possible. The compiled regex should theoretically be able to search the inscriptions much faster.

Comment: Similar approach would be a _ternary search trie_ of the stems.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Thank you for the idea! Do you mean something like: r'\b(?:stem1|stem2| [...] |stem35321)ens(?:ending1|ending2| [...] |ending20)\b'?

Also, how could I extract the data from several rows of both dataframes and add them to the matches if there is a match? So far, I think the regex might find the matches quickly, but I need that resulting matches dataframe to continue working with...

Comment: Right, I meant such a regex but the stems should be in a capturing group for further processing. It is necessary to build a dataframe where each stem has its own row. I recommend a separate df linking each stem to its location using the index or a separate id of the locations df. Using methods `str.extract` or `str.extractall` on inscriptions df gives us the matching stems. `merge`ing this with the stems df gives the location ids and merging this with the locations df gives the full location information.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could build a single regex from the stems:

```
pattern = f"""({
   df_locations["stem"].str.replace(", ", "|").str.cat(sep="|")
})"""
```

```
>>> pattern
'(Rom|Londini|Londin|Coloni|Colon|Agrippin|Vindobon|Luteti|Lutet|Parisior)'
```

```
>>> df_inscriptions["text"].str.extract(pattern)
     0
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  NaN
3  Rom
4  NaN
```

You could use this to then merge the locations:

```
>>> df_inscriptions["stem"] = df_inscriptions["text"].str.extract(pattern)
>>> df_inscriptions.merge(df_locations)
   id                text  findspot   comment stem period  name  long   lat  latlong
0  a3  text with Romensis  Berkeley  mulieris  Rom   Roma  50.4  1.23  50.4     1.23
```

Comment: Thank, @jqurious, I'll try to see how I can make this work. It probably will require some creative intermediate steps in order to fully result in what I need (there will be duplicates which I'll need to handle, and entries with identical stems and so forth), but it's a good start. I'll post a solution as soon as I've found one.